# Optimize join query from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables connected with each other by foreign keys (postgresql 13.1).

```
order: order_id, name
sub_order: mainorder, order_id (foreign key to order), detail
task_group: id, group_name
tasks: id, taskname, task_group_id (foregin key to group_name)
task_kind: id, kind_name
task_task_kind: id, kind_id(fk to task_kind), task_id (fk to task)
time_per_project: person, start_time, stop_time, part, order_id (foreign key to sub_order),
```

Hope I described it enough. My query for materialized view is as follow and it works very well:

```sql
SELECT
  so.order_id AS order_id,
  MIN(so.status) AS status_id,
  SUM(AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)) AS total,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN (tasksgroups.id = 1) THEN
      AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)
    END) AS srut,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN (tpp.valve_part_id = 1) THEN
      AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)
    END) AS korpus,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN (tasks_with_kinds.task_kind = 1) THEN
      AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)
    END) AS zwykle,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN (tasks_with_kinds.task_kind = 6) THEN
      AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)
    END) AS wyprawki
FROM
  intranet.sub_orders so
  LEFT JOIN intranet.time_per_project tpp ON so.mainorder = tpp.project_id
  LEFT JOIN intranet.task_task_kind tasks_with_kinds ON tasks_with_kinds.id = tpp.task
  LEFT JOIN intranet.task tasks ON tasks.id = tasks_with_kinds.task_id
  LEFT JOIN intranet.task_group tasksgroups ON tasksgroups.id = tasks.task_group
GROUP BY
  so.order_id
HAVING (SUM(AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)) > interval '0 minutes');
```

I want to add another join with table as follows:

```
article_group: id, group_name
article_cost: id, group_id (fk to article_group), order_id (fk to sub_orders)
```

I ended up with join in subquery as for some projects it counted same row twice or more times

```sql
SELECT
  so.order_id AS order_id,
  MIN(so.status) AS status_id,
  SUM(AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)) AS total,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN (tasksgroups.id = 1) THEN
      AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)
    END) AS srut,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN (tpp.valve_part_id = 1) THEN
      AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)
    END) AS korpus,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN (tasks_with_kinds.task_kind = 1) THEN
      AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)
    END) AS zwykle,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN (tasks_with_kinds.task_kind = 6) THEN
      AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)
    END) AS wyprawki,
  ac.transport,
  ac.service
FROM
  intranet.sub_orders so
  LEFT JOIN intranet.time_per_project tpp ON so.mainorder = tpp.project_id
  LEFT JOIN intranet.task_task_kind tasks_with_kinds ON tasks_with_kinds.id = tpp.task
  LEFT JOIN intranet.task tasks ON tasks.id = tasks_with_kinds.task_id
  LEFT JOIN intranet.task_group tasksgroups ON tasksgroups.id = tasks.task_group
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      soa.order_id AS ordid,
      sum(
        CASE WHEN group_id = 14 THEN
          COST
        END) AS transport,
      sum(
        CASE WHEN group_id = 11 THEN
          COST
        END) AS service
    FROM
      intranet.article_costs
      INNER JOIN intranet.sub_orders soa ON soa.mainorder = project_id
    GROUP BY
      soa.order_id) ac ON ac.ordid = so.order_id
WHERE order_id = 2074
GROUP BY
  so.order_id, ac.transport, ac.service
HAVING (SUM(AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)) > interval '0 minutes' OR ac.transport > 0 or ac.service > 0);
```

I wonder if you think that this query for materialized view is ok?
If true, is it possible to achieve same behavior without having subquery with nested join in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the same behavior without subquery

```
WITH ac as(
SELECT
      soa.order_id AS ordid,
      sum(
        CASE WHEN group_id = 14 THEN
          COST
        END) AS transport,
      sum(
        CASE WHEN group_id = 11 THEN
          COST
        END) AS service
    FROM
      intranet.article_costs
      INNER JOIN intranet.sub_orders soa ON soa.mainorder = project_id
    GROUP BY
      soa.order_id
)

SELECT
  so.order_id AS order_id,
  MIN(so.status) AS status_id,
  SUM(AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)) AS total,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN (tasksgroups.id = 1) THEN
      AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)
    END) AS srut,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN (tpp.valve_part_id = 1) THEN
      AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)
    END) AS korpus,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN (tasks_with_kinds.task_kind = 1) THEN
      AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)
    END) AS zwykle,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN (tasks_with_kinds.task_kind = 6) THEN
      AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)
    END) AS wyprawki,
  ac.transport,
  ac.service
FROM
  intranet.sub_orders so
  LEFT JOIN intranet.time_per_project tpp ON so.mainorder = tpp.project_id
  LEFT JOIN intranet.task_task_kind tasks_with_kinds ON tasks_with_kinds.id = tpp.task
  LEFT JOIN intranet.task tasks ON tasks.id = tasks_with_kinds.task_id
  LEFT JOIN intranet.task_group tasksgroups ON tasksgroups.id = tasks.task_group
  LEFT JOIN ac ON ac.ordid = so.order_id
WHERE order_id = 2074
GROUP BY
  so.order_id, ac.transport, ac.service
HAVING (SUM(AGE(tpp.stop_time, tpp.start_time)) > interval '0 minutes' OR ac.transport > 0 or ac.service > 0);
```

> I wonder if you think that this query for materialized view is ok?

If data or query time too big - use materialize (but before - optimize the query).